# How make tree on Twitter Bootstrap background like on Twitter?

Tags: css, background-image, twitter-bootstrap

I've added the following:

```
body {
  background-image: url(https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/images/themes/theme2/bg.gif);
}
```

But the tree is copied several times and not fixed on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `no-repeat` (to prevent repetition), `top left` (to keep the image at the desired location) and `fixed` (to keep the image fixed when you scroll):

```css
background: url(http://...) no-repeat top left fixed;
```

I have written a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eCkA/1/).

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly the same as on Twitter - it is fixed on the left even when you scroll down.