# Customizing Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter bootstrap and Ruby on Rails to develop an application. The problem is that as soon as I enter a background the color are messed up. So I was wondering how can I change the color of the "Default grid system" and if there are more themes I could use with

```
rails generate bootstrap:themed <model name> -f    ??
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the gem [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) from the look of the generator.

The boostrap:themed really is just applying the markup to views for the model. Look at the template for [twitter-bootstrap-rails / lib / generators / bootstrap / themed / templates / index.html.erb](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/bootstrap/themed/templates/index.html.erb) on github to see what I mean. For instance it makes tables use the bootstrap CSS by rendering a table using `<table class="table table-striped">`. The -f argument is --force (overwrite)

Now this shows you that what you need to do to change the CSS. The easiest way to do this is just to override [the CSS that you want to change](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html).

A good way to do this is put the overriding CSS into app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less (or similar depending on what kind you use)

If I get your question correctly you want to override the @bodyBackground [less variable](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html).

Now, perhaps that is the answer to your question, was quite hard to understand what you were really asking for.

Comment: can i insert an image instead of just changing the color? cause from that link it only gives how to change the background into another color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251293/how-make-tree-on-twitter-bootstrap-background-like-on-twitter https://groups.google.com/group/twitter-bootstrap/browse_thread/thread/7f32ecb457fb287d/e921fa31c986c4f I guess?